# React Breathing Animation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation

I am trying to create a breathing app using React/Typescript. I don't want to use React Native.

I have the breathing circles set up as components, and I have each circle set up with it's own animation, if it has one. (I am not providing this code, because that's not the issue)

What I am having trouble with is getting the animation to run infinitely while maintaining the delay from the setTimeout(). (See code below)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  BreatheInCircle,
  BreatheHoldInCircle,
  BreatheOutCircle,
  BreatheHoldOutCircle,
} from "./BreatheCircle";

const circles = [
  <BreatheInCircle/>,
  <BreatheHoldInCircle />,
  <BreatheOutCircle />,
  <BreatheHoldOutCircle />,
];

const App = () => {

  const [circleArray] = useState(circles);
  const [displayElement, setDisplayElement] = useState(<div></div>);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisplayElement(circleArray[index]);
      setIndex(index + 1);
    }, 4000);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {displayElement}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`enter code here`
```

When I run this now, it will run the useEffect once for each component, then stop. I need the animation to repeat, until I stop it.

***EDIT***

I was able to solve the delay problem I was having, but I still need help with the looping. Below is the updated code with the changing delay.

```
const App = () => {

  const [circleArray] = useState(circles);
  const [displayElement, setDisplayElement] = useState(<div></div>);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const timeoutDelays = [0, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000];

  const changeCircle = () => {
    setCircle(circles[index]);
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(changeCircle, timeoutDelays[index]);
  }, [index]);
```

if setInterval is still a solution, I would like to know how to implement it. Right now, it runs once, then stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you're trying timeout instead of Interval?
Also send some data from parent to child component to update animation this is not important i think.

Comment: When I used setInterval, there was a flash between components as it rendered the next one, and when the animation was finished (and I'm not sure why this happened) it would randomly flash one of the components. It looked like it was freaking out on me. I tried using Timeout, just to see what would happen, and it worked almost perfectly.

Comment: if you want use setTimeout  then after set Index call again setTimeout function. but this is not good.
setTimout called only once but as soon finishes you can recall function

Comment: Can you show me an example? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the final code I used to solve it. It was using setInterval, I just needed to do it correctly. I upvoted user8119020's answer since they led me to the correct way of solving this.

```
const BreatheCircles: FC = () => {
  const [circle, setCircle] = useState(<div></div>);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const circles = [
    <BreatheInCircle />,
    <BreatheHoldInCircle />,
    <BreatheOutCircle />,
    <BreatheHoldOutCircle />,
  ];

  const changeCircle = () => {
    setCircle(circles[index]);
    setIndex(index + 1);
    if(index >= 3) {
        setIndex(0);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(changeCircle, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [changeCircle]);

  return <>{circle}</>;
};
```

There is a delay before the animation starts, but that wasn't the issue. Thank you once again to user8119020 for their help.

******UPDATE********

Hi everyone, I know this is a bit after, but I found a better way to do it using pure CSS. Below is an example of the code I used to create the same breathing function without re-rendering a million times.

I used MUI for creating the stylings in place.

```
const breatheCircles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    breatheCircle: {
      borderRadius: '50%',
      width: '30vh',
      height: '30vh',
      animation: '$breathe 17400ms infinite',
    },
    '@keyframes breathe': {
      '0%': {
        transform: 'scale(.5)',
        backgroundColor: '#71A1C9',
      },
      '24.9%': {
        backgroundColor: '#71A1C9',
      },
      '25%': {
        transform: 'scale(1)',
      },
      '25.1%': {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9833',
      },
      '50%': {
        transform: 'scale(1)',
        backgroundColor: '#FF9833',
      },
      '50.1%': {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
      },
      '75%': {
        transform: 'scale(.5)',
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
      },
      '75.1%': {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9833',
      },
      '100%': {
        transform: 'scale(.5)',
        backgroundColor: '#FF9833',
      },
    },
  })
);

const Breathe: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const circleStyles = breatheCircles();
  const gender = useSelector<State>((state) => state.gender);

return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className={classes.root}>//styled elsewhere
        <div className={classes.circles}>//styled elsewhere
          <div className={circleStyles.breatheCircle} />
          <Counter />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.buttonBar}>
          <ButtonBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I just thought that the community would like to see a more efficient way to animate these circles.

Thank you!